# Count number of elements in a text or list using Spark

Tags: pyspark, accumulator

I know there are different ways to count number of elements in a text or list. But I am trying to understand why this one does not work. I am trying to write an equivalent code to

```
A_RDD=sc.parallelize(['a', 1.2, []])

acc = sc.accumulator(0)
acc.value
A_RDD.foreach(lambda _: acc.add(1))
acc.value
```

Where the result is 3. 
To do so I defined the following function called my_count(_), but I don't know how to get the result. A_RDD.foreach(my_count)  does not do anything. I didn't receive any error either. What did I do wrong?

```
counter = 0   #function that counts elements
def my_count(_):
    global counter
    counter += 1

A_RDD.foreach(my_count)
```

Comment: Mary, can you confirm if the posted answer clarifies your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `A_RDD.foreach(my_count)` operation doesnt run on your local Python Virtual machine. It runs in your remote executor node. So the drives ships your  `my_count` method to each of the executor nodes along with variable `counter` since the method refers the variable. So each executor nodes gets its own definition of `counter` variable which is updated by the foreach method while the `counter` variable defined in your driver application is not incremented.

One easy but risky solution would be to collect the RDD on your driver and then compute the count like below. This is risky because the entire RDD content is downloaded to the memory of the driver which may cause MemoryError.

```
>>> len(A_RDD.collect())
3
```

Answer (score 0):

So what if you were running local and not on a cluster.  In spark/scala this behaviour changes between local and on a clust.  It would have a value as expected locally but in the cluster it wouldn't have the same value it would happen just as you describe...  In spark/python does the same thing happen?  My guess is it does.